# DAML Language Server failed to run java

Tags: daml

I'm trying to setup Visual Studio Code for DAML development on an M1 Mac Mini. I've installed the DAML SDK and installed the VS Code plug-in, but I'm getting this error:

```
damlc: ScenarioServiceException "Failed to run java: fd:23: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)"
[Info  - 8:33:21 AM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
```

I installed the Adoptium versions of OpenJDK as suggested by Digital Asset. That didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

I installed Oracle's Java SE Dev kit 18 and that solved the issue for me.

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk18-mac